# User based permission

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, acl

how I can make a user based permission system?

The basic is: I will have pages (account, foo, bar, etc..) and actions (add, edit, delete, etc..), and, each user can have permissions based on responsabilities.

If, I want a user to add new users, I need to add the page 'user' and action 'add', for instance.

I have tried Cake ACL, but, I can't get a idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cake gives you a great solution for these problems with function isAuthorized().

You can learn it from [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvwQGZ1BxdM) or you can read it from [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html).

```
public function isAuthorized($data){
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implementation of Auth and ACL component is the best idea for user based permission,
for detail study you can refer to following url:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html

This url gives us full implementation of ACL component with example data...
Try this and if have any issue please let me know